# No puedo actualizar mi formulario en Java WEB

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

Estoy intentando realizar un CRUD con Java Web y Mysql, el error sale cuando quiero actualizar un registro.
En mi formulario de actualizar ya tengo el: `(enctype="multipart/form-data")` por ende no se a que se debe dicho error.

```
//ESTE ES EL ERROR

Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2948)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2810)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getPart(Request.java:2979)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(RequestFacade.java:1090)
    controlador.RegistroController.doGet(RegistroController.java:154)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
causa raíz

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.init(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:135)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.getMultiPartStream(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:190)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:209)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:127)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2907)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2810)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getPart(Request.java:2979)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(RequestFacade.java:1090)
    controlador.RegistroController.doGet(RegistroController.java:154)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de registro del servidor.
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de archivo estabas tratando de subir?

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes! Por favor incluye la info completa de lo que intentas hacer. Código del formulario, como texto. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Intento subir una imagen.